# Are worn-out flash memory blocks not deletable?

Tags: storage, smartphone

My phone became very slow so I thought if formatting the internal flash memory completely and doing a block erase/write test could make my phone faster.

However, I've heard that flash memories wear out with erasing as they have a limited number of erasing. It is also impossible to write new data without erasing a whole block of data to change just one bit. Does this mean that if some of my private data (password lists) is on the bad blocks that those blocks are permanently staying there as in they're not deletable? I'm wondering if this is really true because I'd like to throw away my phone then or manually vandalize the flash chip with a needle or a pencil and then give it to a repair service to replace that chip.

Now, during writing this message, I thought of if a flashing program could write zeros into the non-eraseable blocks to destroy the private data and what program it could be. Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: You're missing something: As you said yourself, it is *not possible* to write before erasing the old content. Software can't change this. And it's not that erasing is limited but writing not; instead, both steps are limited.

Comment: And why do you think your memory is worn out in the first place?

Comment: Because the phone is slow regardless of how many times I factory reset it. It's slower than the first time I've got it.

Comment: Flash memory doesn't get slower when it wears out, writes stop working entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You might be onto something there.. flash drives, when close to full have issue making memory available. Because of how NAND works, you can write a block at a time, however you have to short the whole block array to free the data. A batch is freeable when all blocks are 'discarded'. In the background your flash controller is busy shuffling/defragmenting mostly discarded blocks around to make whole batches of memory available if put under memory pressure. That aside, a bad block is a bad block ( damaged transistor) and it usually holds no data, however the way in which the controller deals with it might be lazy/stupid/constrained. It might just do a copy of the remaining data from a batch around damaged blocks in a good array and mark the whole batch as bad ( and leave it as is to avoid future corruption and keep management simple). In time it does add up and actually usable space lessens, and this behind the scene activity does ware out the drive further. Therefore try to keep a good 15% always free. As for you formatting the phone there's no guarantee it's a deep format, it might be a fast format which erases just the partition table. Who knows what the manufacturer chooses to do? If you are that concerned of privacy, then you could open up the phone, identify the memory banks, pry them off the motherboard and melt/microwave them? I also think the question is appropriate for a hardware/systems forum.